# How can I multiply every element in array by -1 in c++

Tags: c++

I have an array of elements and I want to multiply every element in that arr with -1 and store it in another array.

```
int arr1[] ={1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1}
int outputArr[]= {-1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,-1};
```

How do I do it?
I know I can iterate over the loop one at a time but I am looking for a function or something (if it exists ) so that I can preferably do that in a single line.

Comment: Typically, one element at a time. Do you know how to iterate over an array?

Comment: You could switch to using a `std::valarray`, then it just becomes `my_valarray *= -1;`

Comment: @François Andrieux I should have included that in my ques my bad!!.
I know how to iterate and multiply one by one but is there any other way (maybe like a function or something to do that in lesser words?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::tranform` to apply a unary operation to each element.

```
std::transform( std::begin( arr1 ), std::end( arr1 ), std::begin( output ), []( int val ) { 
    return val * -1; 
});
```

You could also use `std::negate`, but keep in mind this is not a multiplication, but instead applies `operator-()`

```
std::transform( std::begin( arr1 ), std::end( arr1 ), std::begin( output ), std::negate<int>() );
```

Note: `std::begin` and `std::end` will only work for the array if `arr1` is defined in the *same* function (i.e. not a parameter to a function).

Also note that `output` must be (at least) the same size as `arr1`.

Comment: [std::negate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/negate) is nice in this case.

Comment: @MarekR, debated that, but the question did say multiply by -1, so kept that. If it's not a primitive type, `val * -1` could be different than `-val`, but I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an output array with the same size of the input array. You can use `std::size` for this since C++17.
2. Walk it, e.g. using `std::transform`, and, for each element `n`, just have `transform` return `-n`.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // transform
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1};
    int outputArr[std::size(arr1)];
    std::ranges::transform(arr1, std::begin(outputArr), [](auto& n) { return -n; });
    fmt::print("arr1 = {}\n", arr1);
    fmt::print("outputArr = {}\n", outputArr);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   arr1 = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
//   outputArr = [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1]
```